# Azure InsertAsync DateTime to SQL.Date

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

User class:

```
public class User
{
    private string id;
    private string nick;
    private string password;
    private DateTime birthday;

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "nick")]
    public string Nick { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "birthday")]
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

On Azure table all the columns are of type nvarchar, except birthday that is of type date. Note the type of birthday in C# class is DateTime and on table is SQL.Date. When I use the method InsertAsync( ) I get an exception. How can I do a good insertion?

Answer (score 0):

The cdate column is the type of string in Azure table.
It was defined as follows.

```
    DateTime createDate;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cdate")]
    public DateTime CreateDate
    {
        get { return createDate; }
        set { createDate = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Azure you just have four kinds of data: String, Number, Boolean and Date.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D9CH.png)

If you open your table on Visual Studio, you will see that the Date type is showed as "dateoffset(3)". I chaged this value to "date" on Visual Studio, and on Azure the type of my field "birthday" was showed as Custom. Because of this I was having problem with InsertAsync.